# Match email with Masterlist Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to match the subject of incoming email with an Excel master list to see if the email was already existing/extracted previously. If match or existing then it will show something or extract a message from the email.

Below code doesn't show any results.

```
Public Sub MatchAutoAckv1()

    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim obj As Object

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items

    Dim myItem As MailItem

    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim TotalRows As Long, i As Long

    Dim myXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim myXLWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim exSubj As String

    Set objOL = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("For Processing")
    Set objItems = objFolder.Items

    Set myXLApp = New Excel.Application
    myXLApp.Visible = True
    Set myXLWB = myXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\SR Automation Project\SR Historyv2.xlsx")

    Set excWks = myXLWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lgLastRow = excWks.Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    i = lgLastRow + 1

    Dim lgCurrentRow As Long

    For Each obj In objItems

        For lgCurrentRow = 2 To lgLastRow
            Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C") = exSubj

            If obj.Subject = exSubj Then

                Debug.Print obj.Subject

            End If

        Next

    Next

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set objItems = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you always use Option Explicit. If you do not know how to declare a variable just leave it without a type.

```
Dim Variable ' as nothing becomes Variant
```

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MatchAutoAckv1()

    'Dim objNS As Namespace
    'Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder ' 2003 and older
    Dim objFolder As folder
    Dim obj As Object

    'Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objItems As Items

    'Dim myItem As mailItem

    'Dim StrBody As String
    'Dim TotalRows As Long
    'Dim i As Long
    Dim lgLastRow As Long
    Dim lgCurrentRow As Long

    Dim myXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim myXLWB As Excel.Workbook

    Dim excWks As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim exSubj As String

    'Set objOL = Outlook.Application
    'Set objNS = Application.Session

    Set objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("For Processing")
    Set objItems = objFolder.Items

    Set myXLApp = New Excel.Application
    myXLApp.Visible = True
    Set myXLWB = myXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\SR Automation Project\SR Historyv2.xlsx")

    Set excWks = myXLWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lgLastRow = excWks.range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    'i = lgLastRow + 1

    'Likely more efficient with loops reversed
    'For Each obj In objItems

    For lgCurrentRow = 2 To lgLastRow

        ' This is the wrong way round
        'excWks.Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C") = exSubj
        exSubj = excWks.Cells(lgCurrentRow, "C")
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print exSubj

        For Each obj In objItems
            If obj.subject = exSubj Then
                Debug.Print "- " & obj.subject
            End If
        Next

    Next

    myXLWB.Close olDiscard
    myXLApp.Quit

ExitRoutine:

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set objItems = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    'Set objOL = Nothing

    Set myXLApp = Nothing
    Set myXLWB = Nothing
    Set excWks = Nothing

End Sub
```